# PHP: Hide file extension from URL using .htaccess

Tags: php

I want to hide file extensions from a URL like
if the current URL is

**http://localhost/salsgiver/administrator/menus.php?sect=about**

then the new one will be exactly

**http://localhost/salsgiver/administrator/menus/sect/about**

and so on, similary if the current URL is

**http://localhost/salsgiver/administrator/products.php?id=1**

then the new one will be exactly

**http://localhost/salsgiver/administrator/products/1**

Or some thing different, so that the viewer could not guess the exact URL.

I searched Google and found some matter on

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/02/hide-php-url-rewriting-htaccess.html

and also used, but it does not work and the `mod_rewrite` module is also enabled in Apache. And when I create the .htaccess file to secure a folder from all using

```
deny from all
```

it works fine.

Comment: The roshanbh.com.np link is broken: *"Forbidden. You don't have permission to access this resource. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. Apache Server at roshanbh.com.np Port 80"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, but mod_rewrite is much easier to use if you use a single index.php which then chooses which file to open (products.php or menus.php)

For a single index file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

For multiple files:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L]
```